# Is it a right choice to transfer large amount of data(i.e., each piece of data about 100MB) through Mqtt?

Tags: tcp, mqtt

Is it a good choice choice to transfer large amount of data (i.e., each piece of data about 100MB) through Mqtt?

Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

ADDED:
As far as I know, it seems that mqtt could support as much as 256MB as the spec . But it's also known that it usually transfers the data that is less than 1MB.

So, I am a little confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT was designed to send telemetry data (usually something under 500 bytes) to multiple nodes, with various QOS ratings.

This is a question that comes up quite frequently here.  When I consult with customers who ask me this kind of question, I always say there are better ways to move large amounts of data to multiple nodes.  Consider these:

1. Copy the large data up to an FTP server, and just send out the address using MQTT.
2. Stream the data using some kind of streaming protocol, or multicast, and just send the stream address over MQTT.

Can you send large data chunks over MQTT?? Yes.  But just because you can do it, does not mean its the best way to do it.  Solutions I design for customers never send anything over 100k or so over MQTT.  It takes up too much bandwidth and can bog down the Broker very quickly, especially with large number of Subscribers.

There are others on here that will tell you for sure, do it, no problem.  I have run into too many issues with too many customers that wanted to do stuff like this, so I never create a solution that uses MQTT for large chunks of data.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid and detailed explanation.